# How to make a child fill all usable screen real estate in Facebook's Litho?

Tags: android, facebook, fullscreen, fill, litho

I am trying to use mapview with Facebook's Litho and i cannot figure out how to make the mapview fill all usable screen real estate.

Is there some method im overlooking? If you figure it out please tell me how also so i can learn how to gather more information!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a code snippet of what you're trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [MountSpec](https://fblitho.com/docs/mount-specs) with the @OnMeasue function.

```
@MountSpec
public class MapComponentSpec {

    @OnCreateMountContent
    static MapView onCreateMountContent(Context c) {
        return new MapView();
    }

    @OnMount
    static void onMount(ComponentContext context,MapView mapView,@Prop String mapData) {
        mapView.doStuff();
    }
}
```